# Composition of two differentiable functions and a related integration and its sign

Tags: riemann-integration

> $f$ and $g$ are two differentiable functions on the *real line* such that $f$ is *strictly increasing* and $g$ is *strictly decreasing*. Define $p(x)=f(g(x))$ and $q(x)=g(f(x))$ for all real number $x$. Then for $t>0$ the sign of $$\int_0^t p'(x)(q'(x)-3)dx$$ is
>
> a)positive
>
> b)negative
>
> c)dependent on $t$
>
> d)dependent on $f$ and $g$.

I am taking particular examples for $f$ and $g$ such as $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$, the results are all positive but cannot find out the general result for all functions having those specified properties.

Comment: Can someone please edit this question for me? I don't know why it's not getting posted fully.

Comment: Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes.Thank you so much José for your help.Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Please learn [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).